# Under iOS 7, how do I make my UITextView's height dependent on the type of device running the app (4 inch screen vs 3.5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uitextview

I have a UITextView that should consume the height of the screen, minus the height of the nav bar and keyboard (as when the view loads the keyboard appears). Obviously on a 4 inch device this means the text view should be slightly taller. Is it possible in Interface Builder to make the height device dependent?

If not, can I do it in code? Is it possible to do without some Auto Layout constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very easy to do it by using Auto Layout constraints. Is there any special reason for not using it?

Comment: No, I was just curious if there was an easy way. I assume I adjust detect the device in code and adjust the constant accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this check in your code, You can use below Macor to check the device:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
```

then:

```
 if (IS_IPHONE5 )
 {
       //textView.frame = ..
 }
 else
 {
       //textView.frame = ..
 }
```

And yes you can do it using a couple of Auto Layout constraints which is the best practice to do that, check this SO question:

[iPhone 4 & 5 Autoresize Vertical Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388638/iphone-4-5-autoresize-vertical-space)

Answer (score 0):

you can use struts and springs.  but auto layout is the new hotness.

[iOS AutoLayout vs Springs & Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739033/ios-autolayout-vs-springs-struts)

Answer (score 0):

Going off null's answer:

Im assuming you are placing this UITextView inside a UIViewController?

You can set the frame for the UITextView at runtime.

In viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    //216 is the height of the keyboard, 20 is the height of the status bar
    if (isiPhone5) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20, self.frame.size.width, 568-216); 
        [textView setFrame:frame];
    }
    else {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20, self.frame.size.width, 480-216); 
        [textView setFrame:frame];
    }


}
```